# Is it correct to say “在手机”？

Tags: grammar, mandarin, usage, preposition

Would it be correct to use the phrase "在手机”/“在手机上” etc. to express that I am doing something on my phone? For example, could I say

> 我听音乐在我的手机上。

Or can 在 only be used for my actual physical location? If so, how would I express this sort of thing? (Phrases like "on the internet", "on my computer", "on my phone", etc.)

Comment: 我在手机上听音乐 or 我在用手机听音乐

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your sample sentence should be "我在我的手机上听音乐" as ChineseHulu.com said.And you actually SHOULD not omit the word "上" in this sentence,or it would be a little bit weird to native Chinese people.

"在...上" is a preposition phrase.It can be used on representational target like:
在操场上 -- on playground
在沙发上 -- on sofa

And it can be used on abstract target like
在手机上 -- on cell phone
在电脑上 -- on computer
在网络上 -- on internet

Usually we Chinese won't omit "上" if we use this phrase on abstract target or express specific position relation.So these sentence should not omit this word:
我正在手机上玩游戏 -- I'm playing game on cell phone.
我想在电脑上看电影 -- I wanna watch movie on computer.
我通常在网络上聊天 -- I usually chat on internet.
男孩在沙发上跳着 -- The boy is jumping on the sofa.

But if we use this phrase to express the location where something happened,not focusing on the position relation.We can omit this word:
男孩们在操场上玩 or 男孩们在操场玩 are all ok.(Boys are playing on the playground.)

And if you wanna express something happened on the specific location but it's a large area.You MUST omit the word "上" and the phrase thus turn into another single word preposition phrase "在...".
我在上海工作 -- I'm working in Shanghai.
我在苏州旅游 -- I'm traveling in SuZhou.

Apologize for my English.Hope you will get it all... :D

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for all your clarification regarding ‘上’! It's incredibly helpful!^.^I totally get it, and I learned a bit of new vocab from your explanation. And seriously, don't worry about your English; I assumed you were a native speaker right up until you apologised for it. xD Thanks again, and have a fabulous day! ^.^

Comment: Glad it is useful to you.And yes I'm native Shanghainese.So I can assure you that my Shanghai dialect and Mandarin are both excellent.For Cantonese,I'm OK but not that good so I will avoid answering question on it to misguide anyone. =)

Answer (score 3):

It is proper to say "在手机”/“在手机上”, "在" doesn't necessarily mean to be at actual physical location.

For your sentence, a better grammar structure should be 我在我的手机上听音乐。In Chinese there is a tendency to put the location preposition as early as possible. In a sentence, in this case, it is right after the subject.

Answer (score 3):

I am doing something on my phone ? Just translate 我在玩手机

“我听音乐在我的手机上。” It is EngChinese. Chinese should be 我在用我的手机听音乐.

"在" Can be used in both location (在北京 , in Beijing) and preposition (在看书, Reading).

Answer (score 2):

I think "在手机" it self has no appropriate meaning.
It's weird that it appears alone.
"我在我的手机上听音乐。"is not common too. 
"I'm online"    `"我在线"`is correct by commonly used.
`"我在用我的手机听音乐"`is correct.
Also you can say`"在手机里面有很多个应用程序"`。

Answer (score 1):

I would say "我**正**在用我的手机听音乐." instead of "我在用我的手机听音乐." because "正在" is a more complete way to express the continuous tense.

And if "my" is not the main idea in the context, I think we can say "我正在用手机听音乐."  It is because cell phone is kinda personal device and it is not likely let others have possession simply for music.

Answer (score 1):

I have a friend,she speak more like"我在我手机听歌”，but actually is "我在我手机上听歌”，in Chinese phrase,prep is most use,In my opinion,this is practicing your listening.Hard to explain in English.

Answer (score -2):

不对， 你可能想说的是我用手机听歌，但是在手机上，会感觉到不自然